# Using cumsum to create a variable that is dependent of previous element in Matlab

Tags: matlab

The equation that I would like to use the cumsum function on is:

[image]

I need to create an array of 50 variables, which are dependent on each other. Theta_0 is given.

I am not sure how to use cumsum function because the current variable depends on previous variable.

Comment: The only way I can see you do this is with a `for` loop.  `cumsum` for the `i'th` entry will rely on all values from index 1 up until `i`.  If you want to compute it for just the previous value by itself (a.k.a. a recurrence relation), I can only see you do this with a `for` loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rewrite your equation like this:

theta_{i+1} =theta_i * [1+  alpha * Delta + Psi * Delta^0.5 *Z_{i+1} ]

let x_i = log(theta_i)

x_{i+1} = x_i +log[1+  alpha * Delta + Psi * Delta^0.5 *Z_{i+1} ]

and then

x_k = x_0 + sum_{i=1}^k log[1+  alpha * Delta + Psi * Delta^0.5 *Z_{i} ]

so if in matlab you make the vector v = log[1+  alpha * Delta + Psi * Delta^0.5 *Z]

then

x = x_0 + cumsum(v)